# struts2 jquery with scroll pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery, scroll-paging

Any idea about how can I use ajax scroll pagination in struts2?
I have found some useful content on the web about jquery pagination but I can not integrate it with my struts2 framework.
Here is one example of jquery pagination (on php):
http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/24/create-infinte-scroll-effect-using-jquery-with-demo/

Thanks

Comment: it is basically the same, just try replace `my_scroll_ajax_file.php` to `your-struts2-action`

Comment: I tried but I am novice at javascript and I don't know how to set my action

Comment: post your code, otherwise no one can help you

Comment: actually I found another jquery library and it is working fine for me.
here is the link:
http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/  
and just the name of the action is sufficient for calling the action. 
Thanks anyways